# Iterate over JsonObject properties

Tags: java, json, iteration, gson

I would like to iterate through the big wrapping `JsonObject` with [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). My final aim is to get an `ArrayList` of all existing three digit `code` integers in the inner `"unterfeld"` objects, but that will be no problem once I can iterate through the outer object's properties.

```
{
  "something1": {
    "bezeichnung": "something1",
    "unterfeld": [
      {
        "bezeichnung": "bla1",
        "unterregionen": [
        ],
        "code": 111
      },
      {
        "bezeichnung": "bla2",
        "unterregionen": [
        ],
        "code": 222
      }
    ],
    "code": 3
  },
  "something2": {
    "bezeichnung": "something2",
    "unterfeld": [
      {
        "bezeichnung": "bla3",
        "unterregionen": [
        ],
        "code": 333
      }
    ],
    "code": 6
  },
  "something3": {
    "bezeichnung": "something3",
    "unterfeld": [
      {
        "bezeichnung": "bla4",
        "unterregionen": [
        ],
        "code": 444
      },
      {
        "bezeichnung": "bla5",
        "unterregionen": [
        ],
        "code": 555
      },
      {
        "bezeichnung": "bla6",
        "unterregionen": [
        ],
        "code": 666
      }
    ],
    "code": 9
  }
}
```

Is there any neat way to do that?

Comment: Well-posed question, thank you

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [`entrySet`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#entrySet%28%29) to iterate over the members of the outermost `JsonObject`.

```
JsonObject object;
ArrayList<Integer> codes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
    JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("unterfeld");
    for (JsonElement codeHolder : array) {
        codes.add(codeHolder.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("code").getAsInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot first of all. It is probably my lack of understanding of the Map object, but I get an error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method getAsJsonArray(String) is undefined for the type Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>

Comment: I missed a call to `getValue` to pull the `JsonElement` from the `Map.Entry`.

Comment: At least with version 2.2.4 of GSON, to make it work you have to replace 
`JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray("unterfeld");`

with 
JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("unterfeld").getAsJsonArray();

Comment: @s0nica Quite right. I have fixed that error and others and checked that it compiles in Eclipse.