# Looping through gson object in Java?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, gson

I'm currently working on an Android application that gets a JSON response from a website called CloudMine. Their responses are typically in this format:

```
{
    "success": {
        "key1": { "field": "value1" },
        "key2": { "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" }
    },
    "errors": {
        "key3": { "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" }
    }
}
```

I currently want to loop through all the objects in the "success" object so I can access the different fields in each object. However, I've only been taught how to use the JsonParser from the gson API. The closest I got was using the names() method on the success object but Eclipse yelled at me because the method is undefined for this type.

I appreciate all the help that anyone can give me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
JsonObject myJsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonString, JsonObject.class);

            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : myJsonObject.entrySet()) {

                JsonObject entryObj = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
            }
```

Based on the accepted answer to this question, although I've altered it for my use case:

[Iterate over JsonObject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165088/iterate-over-jsonobject-properties)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very simple code that would iterate over objects in 'success':

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONObject success = json.getJSONObject("success");
JSONObject one;
for(Iterator it=success.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    one = success.getJSONObject((String)it.next());
    //deal with the next object inside your 'success'
}
```

Comment: Don't you just love the downvoters with no comments?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not Gson, as stated in the question.