# Parsing JsonObject's fields regardless of their name

Tags: android, json, gson

I've been looking for this for a while now, but couldn't find it anywhere in SO or in the docs.
I am using Gson to parse a json file, and suppose the file is:

```
{
    "animal":"cat",
    "paws":"4",
    "eyes":"2"
}
```

Now, since all the fields are strings, I want to parse it as an array of strings, I want something like:

```
{"cat","4","2"}
```

And I would like to parse the `JsonObject` regardless of the name of its tags, and that's where the problem lies. I can garantee the json will contain only strings, but I have no clue of what the fields are going to be named.

Anyone ever faced this problem ? Any help is much appreciated, and any research direction also.

#### Edit

From the anwers, I managed to do it like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : object.entrySet()) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165221/1341626)

Comment: this is dangerous. object are not sorted, therefore depending on the implementation, you may retrieve `"4", "cat", "2"` or any other order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject` has the `keys()` method that returns an `Iterator<String>`. Through the iterator you can retrieve the value associated with each key. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) the documentation

EDIT:
 Since you are using `GSON` , you can retrieve the keys through the method `entrySet()`

Comment: Please, note that I am using Gson, the class `JsonObject` has no such method. Although looking for keys I found `entrySet()` which will serve the same pourpose, if you could modify your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Iterator`, which you can get by calling `.keys()` on your `JSONObject`. I think something like that should work (using `org.json` library):

```
String[] output = new String[jsonObject.length()];
Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keys();
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    output[i++] = jsonObject.optString((String) iterator.next());
}
```

**EDIT** Ok, in case of `GSON` it will be like this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = jsonObject.entrySet();
String[] out = new String[set.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> x : set){
    out[i++] = x.getValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi, as I stated in the question, I am using the Gson library.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gson then simple solution is :

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(YOUR_JSON_STRING, mapType);
// get only values from map
Collection<String> values = map.values();

for (String string : values) {
  // do your stuff here
}
```

result values collection contains

```
[cat, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(parentJson.getJSONObject("objectname")
            .toString());
 Iterator<?> iter = jsonObject.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
  String key =(String) iter.next();
  String value =  jsonObject.getString(key);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. As I stated in the question, I am using the Gson library.