# Gson object by object parsing for objects with different names everytime

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to consume data from a service with following JSON fromat :

```
{
  "field1": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "complexfield": {
    "name1": {
      "key": "value"
    },"name2": {
      "key": "value"
    },"name3": {
      "key": "value"
    },"name4": {
      "key": "value"
    },"name5": {
      "key": "value"
    },"name6": {
      "key": "value"
    },"name7": {
      "key": "value"
    }
  },
  "field2": {
    "key": "value"
  }
}
```

Here `field1 & field2` are having constant format for which I can create a pojo, but for `complexfield` the inner `name` object will be different each time (i.e. format will be same but its `name` will change everytime). Also `complexfield` is not an array to iterate over it, its a object. One thing is clear I cannot create pojo for this I have to go Object by Object, but how am I suppose to fetch the complexfields inner object having different names in every response ? using `getAsJsonObject("what to pass here as name ?")` ?

**OR**

Can I iterate over such complex Object by getting name of each sub object @ runtime ?

Comment: If the array of complexField nested POJOs is finite - you can make register a custom deserializer, otherwise - you can deserialize complexField into a Map<String,Object>, right?

Comment: The major problem here complexfield is not an array its an JSON object. Also the format of this inner name object different in few cases.

Comment: By "finite array of nested POJOs" I've meant the list of possible nested objects. You can register a custom deserializer for the whole object of yours and deserialize complexField as a Map http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096940/how-do-i-write-a-custom-json-deserializer-for-gson Another example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590377/custom-json-deserializer-using-gson

Comment: @ Роман Гуйван yep that's correct, but the name here is required for processing. Whatever appears within the object is dependent on its name.

Comment: In case you deserialize regular fields as POJO fields and deserialize complexfield contents as Map<String,Object> - you will not face this problem, because writing your custom deserializer will allow you to process JSON as a tokken stream, so You'll definitely will be able to get all the key/value pairs from complexfield JSON object and put those into a map

Comment: @РоманГуйван I tried working on your suggested thing it seems pretty complex to me can you create pojo for above, that will help me solve above issue ?

Comment: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/ just follow this example

Answer (score 0):

We finally ended up using `entrySet()` method of Gsons `JsonObject` class. Ref : http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#entrySet()

Where I get the key as strings and sub object as `JsonElement`.

How to use this ? 
Here is a stackoverflow thread :[Iterate over JsonObject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165088/iterate-over-jsonobject-properties)